# new website is not loading theme css in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento

i've created a new website under a working Magento install. The old website works fine, but the new one doesn't load the theme css. I can see it loads the .phtml files when enabling Template Path Hints.
I've already checked basic things 100 of times, so...

Answer (score 0):

1. set theme to desired one
2. refresh Magento cache
3. check source code to see whats the css path
4. use i.e. firebug to see what css is being loaded

can you show your file structure?

whats the theme name?

Comment: 1 and 2 already done. There's no css path when checking with firebug

Comment: the file structure is the same than any theme, the files are correctly placed, same on system.configuration.design